# Typescript undefined variable, grabbing from external file

Tags: javascript, typescript, variables, undefined

I am trying to use a variable from a JavaScript file that gets downloaded via the `<script>` tag however typescript complains because it is undefined. I cannot define the variable otherwise it takes precedence and then I cannot access the other one.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you please share code of the second JavaScript file that get downloaded and include the variable you're trying to access? As there might be a chance that the variable you are trying to access have private scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
declare var myVar;
```

to the beginning of your TypeScript file. This informs TypeScripts of its existence, without re-declaring it.

Comment: My damn thank you so much. Have been banging my head for hours. Really appreciate it I will remember to do that when ever I use imported files. Wish I could give you 100 votes for pain you released me of.